# Adding salt and pepper noise to an image in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pycharm, spyder

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def add_saltpepper_noise(image_):
    s_vs_p = 0.5 #%50
    amount = 0.004
    noisy = np.copy(image_)

    num_salt = np.ceil(amount * s_vs_p * image_.size) #piksel * miktar * tuz biber oranı
    coords = [np.random.randint(0,i-1,int(num_salt)) for i in image_.shape]
    noisy[coords] = 1 #beyaz

    num_pepper = np.ceil(amount * (1-s_vs_p) * image_.size)
    coords_ = [np.random.randint(0,i-1,int(num_pepper)) for i in image_.shape]
    noisy[coords_] = 0 #siyah

    return noisy


img = cv2.imread("NYC.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) / 255
goster(img,"Orijinal")
n_img = add_saltpepper_noise(img)
goster(n_img,"Salt & Pepper Noise")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.show() #tüm figürleri göster
```

The code block I wrote is as seen above.

When I run this code with the Spyder editor, I get the result I want, but when I work with Pycharm, it does not give the same result. I want to write my codes on Pycharm.
[when run with Spyder Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39HrX.png)
[when run with Pycharm Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v7v3.png)

Comment: Whatever is `goster()` is not defined and can't be reproduced.

Comment: As stateMachine commented, the issue is related to `goster` method. We may replace `goster(n_img,"Salt & Pepper Noise")` with standard methods:  `plt.figure()`;`plt.imshow(n_img)`;`plt.title('Salt & Pepper Noise')`. We may also try convert `n_img` to `uint8`: `goster((n_img*255).round().clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8), "Salt & Pepper Noise")`

Comment: I didn't add it here because the show method is defined, it's just unimportant. All the show method does is "return plt.figure(), plt.imshow(image), plt.title(title), plt.axis("off")".

Comment: Rotem I tried what you stated in the last statement but it didn't change anything.